# More efficient MemoryStream

Tags: .net, performance, memorystream

.Net's MemoryStream has a single large byte array.  When it fills, a new one is created with double the size.  This causes lots of copies, it may fragment the heap, fail before all memory is used for not finding a large enough chunk and put pressure on the large object heap.

The solution is to use several but smaller arrays, as StringBuilder does.  Is there a (semi) standard implementation of this technique for a Stream subclass in the framework or elsewhere?  I know about http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348590/A-replacement-for-MemoryStream, but figured this may be already done somewhere on the framework.

Comment: You are talking about *ropes*.  No, only StringBuilder uses that strategy.  The operating system already provides a very good alternative for a large MemoryStream that still uses the RAM that the machine has available but doesn't use the LOH.  It is FileStream.  And of course you stop fretting completely by just setting your EXE project's Target Platform to AnyCPU, 32-bit operating systems are rapidly becoming a historic footnote.

Comment: A FileStream to a temporary, delete-on-close, file is a great idea.  I'll post in CodeProject.

Comment: You can try this (or rewrite):
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Remoting/channels/core/chunkedmemorystream.cs